# Caching problem in dynamically added javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, google-chrome-devtools

I have a div in my HTML page:

```
<div id="dynamicScript"></div>
```

I generate a dynamic JS code on a textbox blur operation:

```
var dynamicScriptText = `$(document).on('click','#${id}',function(){alert();});`;
```

Now, I have created a script using JS. But I am deleting the script first if it already exists and then regenerate it with an dynamic id and appending it to my `dynamicScript` DIV:

```
        var id = "ControlTool10706547031";
        var elem = document.getElementById("script" + id);
        if(elem){
            elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
        } 
        var script;
        script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.id = "script" + id;
        script.innerHTML = dynamicScriptText;
        var dynSc = document.getElementById('dynamicScript');
        dynSc.appendChild(script);
```

This code generates following output when I inspect element in Chrome DevTools:

```
<div id="dynamicScript">
    <script type="text/javascript" id="scriptControlTool10706547031">
         $(document).on('click','#ControlTool10706547031',function(){alert();});
    </script>
</div>
```

Here, `#ControlTool10706547031` is a button and on click of it I am trying to show an alert.
But the problem is, on textbox blur, although I am deleting the script each time by the following code before re-appending it:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("script" + id);    
if(elem){
         elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}
```

it is somehow caching the generated JS code and suppose if I run my textbox blur operation 5 times, when I click my button `#ControlTool10706547031` the alert message is coming 5 times although when I inspect element in Chrome DevTools:

```
<div id="dynamicScript">
    <script type="text/javascript" id="scriptControlTool10706547031">
         $(document).on('click','#ControlTool10706547031',function(){alert();});
    </script>
</div>
```

This code is showing once.

Comment: Deleting the script element doesn't remove the listeners or the code that already ran.

Comment: @palaѕн $(document).off('click','#${id}') work! Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have added it as an answer with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.off()`](https://api.jquery.com/off/) method here. The `.off()` method removes event handlers that were attached with `.on()`. Calling `.off()` with no arguments removes all handlers attached to the elements. Specific event handlers can be removed on elements by providing combinations of event names, namespaces, selectors, or handler function names like:

```
`$(document).off('click','#${id}').on('click','#${id}',function(){alert();})`;
```